# Owin self-host Web API 405 method not allowed on DELETE

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, katana, http-status-code-405

I am creating an Owin self-host Web API and getting a 405 method not allowed response when posting a DELETE request the server.  POST and GET seem to work with not problems.

I can reproduce the error in the ASP.Net Sample application OwinSelfHostSample project at https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OwinSelfhostSample/ReadMe.txt

I do not have WebDAV installed and using Fiddler the request is formed with no apparent issues.  I also have Cors installed and set to AllowAll.

Any suggestions as to what is blocking 405?

Comment: Please post full web.config. Also the last person to tell me they "haven't installed WebDAV" had WebDAV installed >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I know this is lame but I found the problems minutes after posting this.  I did spend about 3 hours trying to figure this out.  Apparently the issue was with Routing.  My ID is a string so I gave it the action parameter the name of the column instead of "id" which is what the default route is configured to look for.
Once I changed the action parameter name to "id" it worked as expected.